# How to convert Rich Text RTF to plain or HTML in Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, rtf, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

In Delphi XE4 FireMonkey, I have some RTF in a stream from a database. It uses only fonts, sizes, bold and italics.

How can I extract the plain text or convert it to HTML?

Can I somehow use ***JVCL's*** component(s) even though I'm using `FireMonkey`?

Comment: Have you tried a search engine (for example with the keywords delphi rtf html converter library)? (disclaimer: I am the author of a commercial converter library / component for Delphi / Free Pascal)

Comment: TRichEdit can degrade RTF to plain easily.

Comment: Windowless rich text control is the usual way. Tricky to call from Delphi due to its use of ms fastcall.

Comment: The key is "FireMonkey."  If I had access to TRichEdit this job would be so over.:)

Comment: I have checked out the documentation for the ScroogeXHTML solution and it's still not clear to me if it will work inside of FireMonkey. I don't need it to be cross platform.

Comment: If you don't need cross platform then you can use rich edit. Why do you think otherwise? You'd normally want windowless rich text though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The reason I thought I couldn't use a TRichEdit in FireMonkey is that there simply wasn't one available in the component palette. I've since figured out how to create a VCL one in code and get it to convert RTF to plain text.

Comment: Using a windowed control is a little heavyweight for this task, but of course it does work#. That's why windowless rich text exists. But it's a shame it's so hard to reach.